# Makefile doesn't work with "modules"

Tags: linux, make, makefile

I have this makefile of WrapFS. My problem is that make doesn't work when I add "modules" to all part. When I delete "modules", make works, yet doesn't generate wrapfs.ko.

```
WRAPFS_VERSION="0.1"

EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DWRAPFS_VERSION=\"$(WRAPFS_VERSION)\"

obj-$(CONFIG_WRAP_FS) += wrapfs.o

wrapfs-y := dentry.o file.o inode.o main.o super.o lookup.o mmap.o 

KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

What should I change to make it works to generate wrapfs.ko?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this makefile? What are "modules"? You should specify dependencies for your targets to make sure they are evaluated as expected.

Comment: I want to Build the wrapfs module.